# How to create a column based on multiple criteria in r?

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-conditions

Currently I have a variable "Sex" that contains 1's and 2's for respectively men and women. I want to add random noise to this variable. Therefore I generated random numbers using a normal distribution. The next step is to determine if some of the values have to change to the other sex. I use a z-value of 2 and -2 as boundaries. So if a man (1) is assigned to a value >2, it has to change to a woman. It works also the other way around, so when a woman (2) is assigned to a random z-value of <-2, the sex variable has to change to man (1). In all the other options, the value has to remain the same value.

I thought a ifelse statement would do the trick. Unfortunately it did not work. My statement looks like:

```
with(Dataset18$New_sex,
     ifelse(Sex== 1 & Norm_dist_random > 2, 2 , ifelse(Sex== 1 & Norm_dist_random <= 2, 1, 
     ifelse(Sex== 2 & Norm_dist_random < -2, 1, ifelse(Sex== 2 & Norm_dist_random >= -2, 2))))
)
```

My data looks like:

```
Sex     Norm_dist_random
 1         0.622221897
 1         2.573726407
 1        -0.298095612
 1         0.717745305
 2        -2.597695772
 2         2.534427904
 2         0.089732903
 2        -0.329274570
 2        -1.173434147
```

In the end my data has to look like

```
Sex     Norm_dist_random   Sex_new
 1         0.622221897        1
 1         2.573726407        2
 1        -0.298095612        1
 1         0.717745305        1
 2        -2.597695772        1
 2         2.534427904        2
 2         0.089732903        2
 2        -0.329274570        2
 2        -1.173434147        2
```

Comment: You can do that with `case_when` from `dplyr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is with `case_when` which allows an arbitrary set of logical condition value pairs. Each argument is a left hand side that evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE` and a right hand side that defines the value. The two sides are separated by `~`.

Conditions are tried in order until one is `TRUE` and that value is assigned. I added `TRUE ~ NA_real_` to catch the rows that don't fulfill any conditions.

```
library(dplyr)
Dataset18 %>% 
  mutate(Sex_new = case_when(Sex == 1 & Norm_dist_random <= 2 ~ 1,
                             Sex == 1 & Norm_dist_random > 2 ~ 2,
                             Sex == 2 & Norm_dist_random < -2 ~ 1,
                             Sex == 2 & Norm_dist_random >= -2 ~ 2,
                             TRUE ~ NA_real_))
#  Sex Norm_dist_random Sex_new
#1   1        0.6222219       1
#2   1        2.5737264       2
#3   1       -0.2980956       1
#4   1        0.7177453       1
#5   2       -2.5976958       1
#6   2        2.5344279       2
#7   2        0.0897329       2
#8   2       -0.3292746       2
#9   2       -1.1734341       2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
#Code
Dataset18$New_sex <- ifelse(Dataset18$Sex==1 & Dataset18$Norm_dist_random>2,2,
                            ifelse(Dataset18$Sex==2 & Dataset18$Norm_dist_random<(-2),1,Dataset18$Sex))
```

Output:

```
Dataset18
  Sex Norm_dist_random New_sex
1   1        0.6222219       1
2   1        2.5737264       2
3   1       -0.2980956       1
4   1        0.7177453       1
5   2       -2.5976958       1
6   2        2.5344279       2
7   2        0.0897329       2
8   2       -0.3292746       2
9   2       -1.1734341       2
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
Dataset18 <- structure(list(Sex = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Norm_dist_random = c(0.622221897, 
2.573726407, -0.298095612, 0.717745305, -2.597695772, 2.534427904, 
0.089732903, -0.32927457, -1.173434147)), row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = "data.frame")
```